# In solidity, how to copy a string or pass it by value?

Tags: solidity, string, memory, memory-pointer

In this example I only modify string a, but both a and b are changed. It seems like the string wasn't copied. I only want to change a. How do you copy a string and how do you pass a string by value to another function?

```
function test() public view returns (string memory, string memory)
{
    string memory a = "Hello?";
    string memory b = a;
    bytes(a)[5] = '!'; // modify string a
    return (a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings and arrays in solidity are never passed by value. The type `string memory` means that the variable contains a memory pointer, so when you assign `a = b` you are only copying the pointer to the string, not the string itself. Therefore, there is only ever one string.

If you want a copy, you will have to manually make a copy.

This function can copy a `bytes memory`, but you can easily cast back and forth between `string memory` and `bytes memory`.

```
function copyBytes(bytes memory _bytes) private pure returns (bytes memory)
{
    bytes memory copy = new bytes(_bytes.length);
    uint256 max = _bytes.length + 31;
    for (uint256 i=32; i<=max; i+=32)
    {
        assembly { mstore(add(copy, i), mload(add(_bytes, i))) }
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Using `copyBytes` in your function would look like:

```
function test() public view returns (string memory, string memory)
{
    string memory a = "Hello?";
    string memory b = string(copyBytes(bytes(a)));
    bytes(a)[5] = '!'; // modify string a
    return (a, b);
}
```

This will return `("Hello!", "Hello?")`