# Does typecasting create a new copy with it's own memory?

Tags: solidity

Consider the following two snippets.

```
bytes memory a = bytes(someThing)
```

and

```
bytes memory a = new bytes(sizeOfSomething)
a = someThing
```

What's the difference? And also, what's the correct way to convert a `string calldata` to a `bytes memory`? The first approach works with `calldata string` but the latter I'm unable to implement as `string` does not support the `length` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An assignment (with out without casting) will not copy the contents.

A reference of a dynamic type (`string` or `bytes`) points to a memory location, where it stores the length and the raw data for this variable.

When you cast a `string` to a `bytes` it will not actually change anything on the storage/memory level. This is more a syntactic/compiler sugar to allow interacting with the data.

If you want to copy the string to another string you would create a new bytes (as you did) and then loop over the original bytes to push each element into the new bytes: [In solidity, how to copy a string or pass it by value?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91406/in-solidity-how-to-copy-a-string-or-pass-it-by-value/91407#91407)

A one liner to copy the string would be:

```js
string memory copySomeThing = string(abi.encodePacked(someThing));
```

Edit:

When using `calldata` for a `memory` variable it will copy the data into memory. This happens each time again when `calldata` is assigned:

```js
contract Converter {
    function convert(uint[] calldata test) public pure returns(uint[] memory test1, uint[] memory test2) {
        test1 = test;
        assembly {
            mstore(test1, 1)
        }
        test2 = test;
    }
}
```

If we input `[1,2,3]` into this function it will return `([1], [1,2,3])`.

Comment: So the second approach I used just creates memory space of `sizeOfSomething` and then points to some reference so, the memory I allocated is considered wasted/unused?

Comment: For context, the `string` in my question is a `calldata` parameter. Which makes solidity actually create a copy right? Because I was able to modify it.

Comment: `calldata` will be copied into memory when you reference it as a value that is required in memory. This is the case when you call any build-in function or precompile with it. The conversion will happen implicitly. And as you mentioned, each time this assignment happens a new copy will be created. (I will add an edit with a small function to show this).

Comment: Understood. So unless we use the `new` keyword and the data location is same for `destination` and `source`, `string memory destination = bytes(source)` is just syntactic sugar right and no memory is allocated?

Comment: yes, that is correct