# How to pass by value in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

I have checked [older posts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91406/in-solidity-how-to-copy-a-string-or-pass-it-by-value) in regards to this topic, but I suppose Solidity got updated in the meanwhile because they are not up-to-date/do not apply anymore.

I have the following contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Person {
    struct Details {
        uint birthYear;
    }

    function use(Details memory d) internal pure {
        Details memory e = d;
        e.birthYear = 1942;
    }

    function work() public {
        Details memory john;
        john.birthYear = 1992;

        use(john);

        // How do I change the use function so that it logs "Birth year is: 1992"?
        console.log("Birth year is: ", john.birthYear);
    }
}
```

The above code prints "Birth year is: 1942".

Is it possible to pass a `Details` object to the `use` function by value so that the `use` function doesn't change the state of the `john` object?

Comment: Off the top of my head I think the answer is "no", you can't do this in Solidity. But you might want to double check in the [Solidity Matrix server](https://matrix.to/#/#ethereum_solidity:gitter.im).